# Using spring insight with an app that uses spring integration 1.0.4

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to deploy an existing app to tc-server. I have been using this app on tomcat for a couple of years and the production version already runs on tc-server. I have installed the version of tc-server that comes with spring insight. Everything goes well until I deploy a war file that has a dependency on spring integration. I'm getting a no class def found error and it is complaining about a class called 
org/springframework/integration/transformer/AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer
I opened up the spring integration jar that is bundled with my war in the WEB-INF lib and did not see that class. 
 I poked around in the tomcat instance that I created with the bat files in tc-server and see a later version of spring-integration i.e.
.\insight\collection-plugins\insight-plugin-spring-integration-1.9.2.SR1.jar

Since my war is now getting a class not found exception (whereas it deploys fine on my normal tomcat 6.29 ) I'm assuming that this other version of spring-integration is being seen by my app somehow. My app is configured to use spring-integration-1.0.4.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1.0.4 is an extremely old version (3+ years old) the current release is 2.2.4. That class was introduced in 2.0.0.

So you probably have a classpath issue - insight needs a more recent version of Spring Integration on the classpath.

The insight plugin version (1.9.2.x) is not related to the Spring Integration version (but it needs a much more recent version than 1.0.4).

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Most likely I'll just delete my integration beans for deploying with spring insight. There are only a couple of jobs and nothing really depends on them. I don't really understand class loading well enough to try and and isolate my stuff from the spring stuff.